# In Powershell 5.1, how to capture warnings from a remote Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to capture the contents of the warning stream when I do an invoke-command and can't seem to get it - everything I do, the warning goes through to the console instead of into my variable.

Here's the basic snippet to start with:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test'
}
```

as expected, this yields

```
WARNING: Test
```

but then I try to intercept and nothing works:

## Redirection

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test'
} 3>&1
```

Nope,

```
WARNING: Test
```

is emitted into the console, and `$output` is empty.

## WarningVariable

```
$warnings = $null
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test'
} -WarningVariable $warnings
```

```
WARNING: Test
```

is emitted into the console, and `$warnings` is empty.

## WarningAction

Even `WarningAction = 'SilentlyContinue'` doesn't block this.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test'
} -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Is there no way do proper warning-stream passthrough in invoke-command?

#Internally Redirect

From Doug Maurer - redirect internally than capture

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test' 3>&1
}
```

But in order to parse the warnings back out of other return values, I'd have to do something like

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
  Write-Warning 'Test' 3>&1
} | foreach-object {
  if(($_ | Get-Member).TypeName -like '*.WarningRecord') {
    Write-Warning $_.InformationalRecord_Message
  } else {
    $_
  }
}
```

which works, I suppose, but is kind of monstrous?  Do I need to make a complete wrapper for Invoke-Cmd that handles exploding back out the Warning and Verbose and Information records?

Comment: Check my edit for other options

Answer (score 3):

You need to redirect on the remote endpoint, as it is emitting the warning, not `Invoke-Command`

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer {
    Write-Warning 'Test' 3>&1
}

$output
```

**EDIT**

You could return a custom object with properties that include normal output, warnings, errors, etc and then process those. This example is using `$PSDefaultParameters` to specify a warning/error variable and warning/error actions of silentlycontinue for all commands. The + on the variable name means each command that runs will append to that variable. This is one way to handle it.

```
$output = Invoke-Command "kids1","kids2" {
    $PSDefaultParameterValues["*:WarningAction"] = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $PSDefaultParameterValues["*:ErrorAction"] = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $PSDefaultParameterValues["*:WarningVariable"] = '+warnings'
    $PSDefaultParameterValues["*:ErrorVariable"] = '+errors'

    Write-Warning "Test warning"
    Write-Error "Test Error"

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Output       = 'Some output we wanted'
        Warning      = $warnings
        Error        = $errors
    }
}

foreach($warning in $output.warning){
    Write-Warning $warning
}

foreach($err in $output.error){
    Write-Error $err
}
```

However, a slight adjustment to your example I think provides a more robust solution. We'll redirect all streams and then use a switch statement to process the results. For simplicity and readability, the commands have been grouped in a subexpression `$()` and all streams are redirected with one `*>&1'. In the end, only the output should be present in` $output` while the warning, verbose, and error messages are presented as they are received.

```
$output = Invoke-Command $remoteServerList {
    $(
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Write-Warning "[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Test warning"
    Write-Verbose "[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Test Verbose" -Verbose
    Write-Error "[$env:COMPUTERNAME] Test Error"
    ) *>&1
} | ForEach-Object {
    switch ($_){
        {$_.writewarningstream} {Write-Warning $_.informationalrecord_message}
        {$_.writeverbosestream} {Write-Verbose $_.informationalrecord_message -Verbose}
        {$_.writeerrorstream  } {Write-Error $_.Exception.Message}
        default {$_}
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh.  That works but now the warnings are mixed in with all the other output and I have to sort it back out.

Comment: Brilliant!  Works fantastic, Thank you.  @Pxtl, it doesn't mix,  just pipe after the switch and handle your regular output there.